# Configurable AngularJS App

Tags: angularjs, configurable-product

This is my first post here, apologize if my English is not perfect....

I am going to give you a short example of want I am looking for, and I will appreciate your opinion about the best approach to solve the described scenario.

I am not an expert frontend developer, so I if something it is not clear, please not hesitate to ask it.

[Example of app OOTB]

We have application with frontend, backend and database totally working with the following data model:

-Clients { Name , Address }

-Products { Name , Price }

-Orders { ProductID , ClientID , Delivery Date}

So, at this point we have one app that allows users:

CRUD orders , clients and products

*CRUD =  Create, read, update and delete

[Challenge]

How can I design the app to make it configurable?

When I say configurable means not coding the views and the model again, means having  one code that could generate the views and model from a config file.

Let me give an example of configurable:

We have the app OOTB (out of the box) as explained previously, but now we have a different client and  the app need changes:

-Clients { Name, List of Addresses , Phone , Bank account , etc...}

-Products { Name, CreationDate, Price , ExpirationDate , etc...}

How can I code the frontend with angularJS or any other framework to make the views and the model configurable?

Comment: Your question is not very specific.  It sounds like you need to do a lot of tutorials for AngularJS or ASP .NET MVC before you can start making your site.

Comment: It's not a technical question about AngularJS. In my post, I presented a simple business need, you have one app and this app will change for every customer. I am looking for some kind of recommendation or experiences about developing configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a relatively simple website with use authentication / login.

Try this tutorial and see how you get on:
[Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)